# Why is “others” used here?

Tags: word-usage

During my English test, I wrote the following sentence:

> There’re many people in the park. Some are walking; **the others** are flying kites.

My English teacher says that “the others” is wrong, and the correct word is “others” because “the people in the park” is too broad. Is he right? When should I use “others” instead of “the others”?

Comment: I know this isn't the subject of the question, but let me add that "there're" isn't really a word anyone uses or writes down.  I *guess* maybe it's legitimate but I did a double-take when I saw it.  Nearly everyone would just say "there are."

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Actually, it's often spoken, and sometimes used in written dialog to indicate the shortening of the expression when spoken. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12865/is-therere-similar-to-theres-a-correct-contraction

Comment: @barbecue1: Even the people who claim to say it out loud are saying it looks weird written out, and there's some disagreement there as to whether it's even possible to say out loud.  So I think it's at least worth avoiding unless you're sufficiently experienced with English to have a pretty strong opinion in favor of using it.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but the meanings are different.

> Some are walking: the others are flying kites.

The use of the definite article **the others** means that **all** of the people who are not walking are flying their kites: if 70% are walking, the other 30% are flying kites.

> Some are walking:  others are flying kites.

Without a definite article, **others** means that **some** of the people who are not walking are flying their kites: if 70% are walking, 30% or fewer of the people are flying kites.

Comment: +1, though for the first meaning I think that "the rest" would be more idiomatic than "the others".

Comment: @ruakjh, This Ngram graph shows that "the others are" is about twice as common as "the rest are". https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+rest+are%2Cthe+others+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3

Comment: I'm not saying that "the others" is *never* idiomatic in *any* context; only that in this sentence, with the meaning you describe, "the others" is less idiomatic than "the rest".

Comment: ngram frequency isn't meaningful for spoken English.

Comment: @barbecue, "isn't meaningful for spoken English" is a bit strong. "is more reliable for written English" is probably closer to the truth. Anyway, the OP's question is a about awritten test, so NGram evidence should be admissible even by you.

Comment: @ruakh, do you have any references to back up your opinion about usage in this particular context?  If not, I respectfully suggest that you are in the one-third of people who prefer "the rest", where the other two thirds prefer "the others"

Comment: @JavaLatte: According to the Google Books Ngram Viewer, "the rest of the people" is more than a thousand times as common as "the others of the people". [[link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+rest+of+the+people%2Cthe+others+of+the+people&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20rest%20of%20the%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20others%20of%20the%20people%3B%2Cc0)]

Comment: @JavaLatte What I should have said was "Ngram results are not really meaningful for conversational English" because they are based on written sources which skew heavily towards formal technical and scientific writing, and because the actual popularity/usage of a given phrase cannot be determined solely by how many books include it. A [best-selling novel and an obscure scientific treatise](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bronchodilator%2Cdumbledore&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&case_insensitive=true) are equal in ngrams.

Comment: @ruakh, of course it is, because "the others of the people" is ungrammatical- just check actual instances of your NGram search and you will see that they are not real. The correct usage is "the other people" or "the others".  This NGram graph shows that both of these are more common than "the rest of the people".  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+rest+of+the+people%2C+the+other+people%2C+the+others&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20rest%20of%20the%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20other%20people%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20others%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @barbecue, I think that NGram searches are a pretty good indicator of usage, as long as you look at actual instances to check that search is giving you data that is representative of the usage that you are looking for. If you had looked at the actual examples, you would have seen that relevant occurrences of :"the others" is significantly more common than for "the rest". Anyway, the OP's question isn't about conversational English: it's about a sentence that the OP **wrote** in a test, and the sentence is in present simple, which is a largely **written** narrative style.

Comment: @JavaLatte: I'm glad you now accept that context is relevant, and that a simple Ngram search is not always enough to elucidate details.

Comment: @JavaLatte why do you assume I didn't look at your examples? I did. Also, you seem to be misunderstanding me. Conversational English is written down all the time, as for example in handwritten notes, emails, and yes, language learning tests. NGrams excludes all of those sources. It only includes published books. A huge limitation when you are talking about English as spoken and written in everyday conversation.

Comment: ruakh, barbecue, we are digressing. I maintain that the NGram evidence that I quoted was adequately checked and is a relevant and reasonable response to ruakh's comment. You two dispute my evidence but have not provided any evidence at all to back up ruakh's comment. That is my final comment on the subject. If you wish to further discuss the admissibility of evidence on ELL,  I suggest that you each write a meta post about it.